# Problem with taking an array to a certain power

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

So I'm trying to get a difference between certain row of a matrix and a pixel, and I'm getting an error.

Where colorPal is a 8x3 matrix:

```
colorPal = np.matrix('0., 0., 0.;'
                    '0., 0., 1.;'
                    '0., 1., 0.;'
                    '0., 1., 1.;'
                    '1., 0., 0.;'
                    '1., 0., 1.;'
                    '1., 1., 0.;'
                    '1., 1., 1.;')
```

, and I'm trying to subtract three values from RGB channels from certain row of that matrix:

```
colorPal[0] - pix
```

where pix is:

```
    a certain pixel with 3 channels (RGB) from image, 
and I'm accesing it by specifying row and column of that image (img):
    
So, pix = img[i,j]
```

For first row of colorPal and that certain pixel values are:

```
colorPal[0] = [[0. 0. 0.]]
pix = [0.81 0.81 0.81]
```

And after that operation above (`colorPal[0] - pix`) I'm getting a result:

```
[[-0.81 -0.81 -0.81]]
```

So it's getting subtracted. Now I want to take that whole row to second power (`(colorPal[0] - pix)**2`). But numpy throws this:

```
raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')                                                                                   
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

How can I raise this whole row to the second power? What's wrong in this code?

Comment: What version of numpy and Python are you using? Your initial code fragment won't run on Python 3.10 and numpy 1.22.0. (the final `;` is offending)

Comment: Weird. I have python 3.10.4, and numpy is 1.21.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you define it as a 2D matrix and the slice you're taking from it with `colorPal[0]` will still be a 2D matrix (even though 1 of the dimension now has size `1`).

If you try to multiply that 2D matrix with itself, it requires the last two dimension to have the same size, which they don't, 1 != 3.

You could do this:

```
import numpy as np


colorPal = np.matrix('0., 0., 0.;'
                     '0., 0., 1.;'
                     '0., 1., 0.;'
                     '0., 1., 1.;'
                     '1., 0., 0.;'
                     '1., 0., 1.;'
                     '1., 1., 0.;'
                     '1., 1., 1.')

pix = np.array([0.81, 0.81, 0.81])

print((np.asarray(colorPal[0]).squeeze() - pix) ** 2)
```

This takes the slice and turns it into an array, with the same size and dimensions, and then squeezes it to turn it into a 1D array, which can be multiplied with itself as required.

Result:

```
[0.6561 0.6561 0.6561]
```

Or you can avoid the complexity, by turning all of `colorPal` into an array first, so you don't have to perform the transformation on every color:

```
import numpy as np


colorPal = np.matrix('0., 0., 0.;'
                     '0., 0., 1.;'
                     '0., 1., 0.;'
                     '0., 1., 1.;'
                     '1., 0., 0.;'
                     '1., 0., 1.;'
                     '1., 1., 0.;'
                     '1., 1., 1.')

pix = np.array([0.81, 0.81, 0.81])
colorPal = np.asarray(colorPal)

print((colorPal[0] - pix) ** 2)
```

Same result.

From your comment to this answer, it appears you want to actually modify or replace `colorPal` with the operation applied to each colour. Once you turn your matrix into an array, that's easy:

```
import numpy as np


colorPal = np.matrix('0., 0., 0.;'
                     '0., 0., 1.;'
                     '0., 1., 0.;'
                     '0., 1., 1.;'
                     '1., 0., 0.;'
                     '1., 0., 1.;'
                     '1., 1., 0.;'
                     '1., 1., 1.')

pix = np.array([0.81, 0.81, 0.81])
result = (np.asarray(colorPal) - pix) ** 2

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[0.6561 0.6561 0.6561]
 [0.6561 0.6561 0.0361]
 [0.6561 0.0361 0.6561]
 [0.6561 0.0361 0.0361]
 [0.0361 0.6561 0.6561]
 [0.0361 0.6561 0.0361]
 [0.0361 0.0361 0.6561]
 [0.0361 0.0361 0.0361]]
```

Or you could do it all in-place after the type conversion:

```
colorPal = np.asarray(colorPal)
colorPal -= pix
colorPal *= colorPal
```

Comment: I see, I see. But how does it exactly work? If I print out colorPal after and before the conversion the insides look the same. Is it just changing the object's type?

Comment: `colorPal` looks the same because the code doesn't modify it (or only changes the type) - I was only showing why you're getting the error you were getting and how to get around it. If you want to update `colorPal` itself, or stored the result of the computation somewhere else, see my update to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you use `np.matrix`. You should use `np.array` instead.

The `*`-operator (`**`-operator)...

- for `np.matrix` is **matrix**-multiplication (and exponentiation).
- for `np.array` is **elementwise** multiplication (and exponentiation).

The issue has *nothing* to do with slices from `np.matrix` maintaining the number of dimensions.

If you do want to keep using `np.matrix`, you'll need `np.asarray()` or `np.array()` to convert matrices to arrays. Then you can enjoy elementwise operations.

Note that the `@`-operator exists and it is defined to be matrix multiplication (on np.array objects). `A @ B` is equivalent to `np.matmul(A, B)`. There also exists `np.dot`. The behavior of these functions is sensitive to the shapes of inputs.